# Stop the DIV from following cursor, when parent.DIV is not hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I need to make a div that follows the cursor along the path. It should also be happening only when cursor is hovering parent.DIV -- moving DIV should stop on it's spot. The problem is that I cannot stop the DIV from following cursor on .mouseout.  I put here a snippet of my code. I guess, I should somehow tell the moving div to stop, but I do not understand how :(

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(MotionPathPlugin);

const target = document.querySelector("#rect");
const path = document.querySelector("#path");

var element = document.getElementById('area');
let normalize;


  function resize() {
    normalize = gsap.utils.normalize(0, innerWidth)
  }
  window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
  resize();


  const tl = gsap.timeline({paused: true})
    .to(target, {motionPath: {
      path: path,
      align: path,
      autoRotate: true,
      alignOrigin: [0.5, 0.5]
    }, immediateRender: true, ease: "none"});

document.getElementById("area").onmouseover = function(){
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", e => tl.progress(normalize((e.pageX) * 3)));
};
document.getElementById("area").onmouseout = function(){
  tl.paused;
};
```

```css
    #area {
      background-color: red;
      width: 40vw;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Try</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div id="area">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 490 300">
    <!-- <path id="path" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" d="M100.8 149.2s74.8-114.7 185.3-85.4 56.5 157.9 165.2 200.9c132.5 52.4 247.8-144 247.8-144"/> -->
    <path id="path" x="130.5" y="73.5" d="M1 219.877C275 255.376 28 -35.6237 457 4.87657V280.376" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>

    <rect id="rect" width="50" height="50" fill="#88ce03">
  </svg>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
<script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/gsap-latest-beta.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/MotionPathPlugin.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>
<!-- <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/Draggable3.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script> -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your mouse move handler function in a variable (`followMouseHandler` in the below snippet) and then use [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) to remove it when the mouse leaves the div.  You can see this working in the below snippet:

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(MotionPathPlugin);

const target = document.querySelector("#rect");
const path = document.querySelector("#path");

var element = document.getElementById('area');
let normalize;


  function resize() {
    normalize = gsap.utils.normalize(0, innerWidth)
  }
  window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
  resize();


  const tl = gsap.timeline({paused: true})
    .to(target, {motionPath: {
      path: path,
      align: path,
      autoRotate: true,
      alignOrigin: [0.5, 0.5]
    }, immediateRender: true, ease: "none"});

const followMouseHandler = e => tl.progress(normalize((e.pageX) * 3));

document.getElementById("area").onmouseover = function(){
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", followMouseHandler);
};
document.getElementById("area").onmouseout = function(){
  tl.paused;
  window.removeEventListener("mousemove", followMouseHandler);
};
```

```css
#area {
      background-color: red;
      width: 40vw;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Try</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div id="area">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 490 300">
    <!-- <path id="path" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" d="M100.8 149.2s74.8-114.7 185.3-85.4 56.5 157.9 165.2 200.9c132.5 52.4 247.8-144 247.8-144"/> -->
    <path id="path" x="130.5" y="73.5" d="M1 219.877C275 255.376 28 -35.6237 457 4.87657V280.376" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>

    <rect id="rect" width="50" height="50" fill="#88ce03">
  </svg>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
<script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/gsap-latest-beta.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/MotionPathPlugin.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>
<!-- <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/Draggable3.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script> -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahh! Thank you so very much! It helped! Thank you, Alexander :)

Comment: Glad to hear this helped!  If this post helped you solve your issue, don't forget to mark it as such by clicking the check on the upper right of the post.  Good luck, and happy coding!